# mod_rewrite rule for urls to one of two directories

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is this possible with mod_rewrite?

```
    www.site.com/userChosenName
```

redirected to

```
    www.site.com/typeA/page.php?username=userChosenName
```

but if userChosenName is not found in the DB, redirected to

```
    www.site.com/typeB/page.php?username=userChosenName
```

I am thinking that I will need some help from PHP in order to accomplish this.

Comment: Alternatively you can use `mod_rewrite` (RewriteMap) with `mod_dbd`. I don't know enough of that to give you a run-down how to do that though.